# MySQL and Python Flask: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, mysql

**I'm using flask framework and MySQL database connector.**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session
import bcrypt
import pymysql
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def add_product_to_cart():
    if _quantity and _code and request.method == "POST":
        conn = mysql.connect()
        cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM product WHERE code = %s", (_code))
        row = cursor.fetchall()

        itemArray = { row['code'] : {'name' : row['name'], 'code' : row['code'], 'quantity' : _quantity, 'price' : row['price'], 'image' : row['image'], 'total_price': _quantity * row['price']}}
```

**I got the error from below code:**

" itemArray = { row['code'] : {'name' : row['name'], 'code' : row['code'], 'quantity' : _quantity, 'price' : row['price'], 'image' : row['image'], 'total_price': _quantity * row['price']}}"**

Answer (score 0):

`cursor.fetchall()` returns a list so you can't use `row['code']` to access the values in that list. You have to iterate through the list and then get the value OR if you're expecting just one row then use `cursor.fetchone()`

##### Option 1

```
data = cursor.fetchall()
for row in data:
    print(row[0], row[1])
```

##### Option 2

```
row = cursor.fetchone()
print(row)
```

Comment: I am writing font-end with database, Option 1 and Option 2 will limit the user to choose the products.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problems. I need to change my MySQL database, so the problems will slove.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).